# Google Drive with same account on different gadget

Tags: google-drive

If you uploaded a file to your Google Drive on your computer will your phone/tab that had the same account will be notified of the file?

Answer (score 1):

No. You will never be notified of file uploads, even in a shared folder. You will only be notified if someone shares an item with you (outside of a shared folder), or if a doc is edited where you have those notifications turned on.